# stop a function jquery from repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery

how i can stop a function from repeating if the div html = Ready, this is my code

```
  (function(){
   var Load_Div_Error = $( ".Load_Div_Error" ).html();

   if(Load_Div_Error == "Ready") {
    $( "div.Load_Div_Error" ).text( "Test" );
   }
   setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);
  })();
```

Comment: The 5th edition of ECMAScript forbids use of arguments.callee() in strict mode.

Comment: To avoid potential issues with `arguments.callee`, name the [`function` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and reference it by that name: `(function checkError() { /* ... */ setTimeout(checkError, 2000); })()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `else` block to your `if`:

```
if(Load_Div_Error == "Ready") {
    $( "div.Load_Div_Error" ).text( "Test" );
} else {
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);
}
```

This was `setTimeout` will kick on only if Div content != Ready

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.html()` may return whitespace around "Ready". remove it before comparing..

```
(function myLoad(){
   var Load_Div_Error = $( ".Load_Div_Error" ).html(); 

   if($.trim(Load_Div_Error) == "Ready") // remove the whitespace before comparing
       $( "div.Load_Div_Error" ).text( "Test" );
   else 
       setTimeout(myLoad, 2000); // run again only if Load_Div_Error != 'Ready'
})();
```

I've replaced `arguments.callee` with a named function because it is forbidden in strict mode - better not to use it

Comment: Note: You don't have to specify the `.replace()` pattern manually. [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) is now a standardized method and [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) can be used for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Timeout` to an variable and clear it after it is no longer needed:

```
(function(){
   var timer;
   var Load_Div_Error = $( ".Load_Div_Error" ).html();

   if(Load_Div_Error == "Ready") {
    $( "div.Load_Div_Error" ).text( "Test" );
    clearTimeout(timer);
   }
   else
    timer = setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);
  })();
```

Or, I'm thinking of clearing an Interval when using the `setInterval` function, which would be better to use instead of `setTimeout`, IMHO.

But yeah, if you just add an else statement and place the `setTimeout` in there, it would work as well, since `setTimeout` doesn't need to be cleared.